# Passing Javascript array values to ruby array value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone tell me the best way to set a javascript array value to ruby array variable

As I am getting java script array values

```
$("input[name='entry_ids[]']:Checked").each(function() {
            selectedGroups.push($(this).val());
           });
```

How can i set a ruby variable?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You can use `$.post` to send an async request with this array in parameters. Then the array will be available in `params` of your controller action.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You say "set a javascript array value", then you say "set a ruby variable". Do you want to set a JavaScript value, or a Ruby value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set ruby variables from JS, JS is a client side programming language therefore the data needs to be sent to your ROR app somehow. If you submit your form as per normal you will have an array of selected values in `params[:entry_ids]`. Otherwise, you can use JS to post an AJAX message to your rails action.

It doesn't look like you're doing anything special though, so I recommend you look at rails forms. If it needs to be asynchronous, use `remote: true` in your form helper.